# What is the title of that novel where an immortal Disciple of Jesus becomes a disillusioned mercenary?

Tags: story-identification, immortality

If you are immortal (and jaded) you could always put your talents to work. Maybe make a little extra dough on the side...

I heard about it in 1983 or 1984. I always meant to get around to reading it, but now I can't remember the name of it.

Comment: How does he get to be immortal? Why is he called "the Apostle"? Does he do his fighting on land, at sea, in space, on other planets, in the past, the present, the near future, the far future? Is he a rifleman, swordsman, artilleryman?

Comment: @user14111 The legend of the John the Apostle being immortal is a very old one. He's called "the Apostle" because he was one of the Apostles of Christ. There have been many stories written of him over the years, but I'm not aware of any that fit OP's bill, alas.

Comment: @user14111 - Some people interpret John 21:22-23 to mean that John the Apostle was granted immortality by Jesus Christ. It's a little obscure, but it is the only explanation I can postulate... until I identify the unknown novel and read the author's interpretation and how he weaves his tale.

Comment: @user14111 - As I mine my memory for more details, it's a bit sketchy. It seems I recall my friend telling me that the protagonist fought in battles in the middle east and Europe, throughout the medieval and renaissance periods. He was still joining conflicts in the twentieth century, in both World Wars. I don't recall anything mentioned about being in the future, near or otherwise. (Now that I'm describing it, it follows the same "immortal mercenary" archetype as Wolverine!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it possible you are thinking of the Casca series of novels? The first one (published in 1979)  is called The Eternal Mercenary. Casca is the Roman soldier who stabbed Jesus Christ with a spear on Golgotha, cursed to immortality.

Wikipedia article here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casca_(series)

Comment: Upon reading your link, other sites, and some reviews, I am convinced that you are correct. (I don't know what the protocol is on this website, but I edited my original question to make it user-friendly for future readers to find the answer to the question.) Thank you so much!

Comment: @JohnWinkelman -- I saw this question earlier today, and I was going to ask about Casca when I got the chance, but I see you beat me to it!